# PIR Sensor activated video

Tags: sensor, video, omxplayer

I've attempted to modify [this script here](https://github.com/ephemeralfuture/trron/blob/master/trron_final_minus1.py), but instead of for 4 video outputs, to only 2. I'm pretty new to programming a pi and am trying to wrap this up for an gallery project. Here is my current script. The video plays currently, but get stuck at the 102 second mark. What I am attempting to do is have a video of an eye closed when in idle state, but when motion is sensored, to have the eye appear to open and look around. Any help is appreciated.

```
from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer 
from pathlib import Path
import time #for determining the time of playback
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #for taking signal from GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO_PIR = 7 #The GPIO is plugged into BCM pin 07 (GPIO pin 26)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIR,GPIO.IN) # Set pin as input
 
Current_Motion  = 0 #the current state of motion detection
Previous_Motion = 0 #the previous state

birdname = "goldfinch"
VIDEO_PATH = Path("/media/pi/ASTEYES/sensor_py_birds.mp4")

player = OMXPlayer(VIDEO_PATH)


''' The following variables need to be changed from one
    program to the next. They are the times when each event happens
    in the videos.'''
eyeclosed = 2 #eyeclosed
eyeopen = 102 #eyeopen

current_mode = 0 #determines which mode the player is in

motion_detect_bool = False #boolean for detecting motion

def eyeclosed_mode():
    player.set_position(eyeclosed)
    print("player seeked to " + str(player.position()) + "for eyeclosed")

def eyeopen_mode():
    player.set_position(eyeopen)
    print("player seeked to " + str(player.position()) + "for eyeopen")


def check_motion_sensor(Current_Motion, Previous_Motion):
    Current_Motion = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR) # Read PIR state
    time.sleep(1)
    if Current_Motion == 1 and Previous_Motion == 0:
        Previous_Motion = 1
        return True
    elif Current_Motion == 0 and Previous_Motion == 1:
        Previous_Motion = 0
        return False

try:
    player.play()
    
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR) == 1: #loop while the motion sensor is setting up and still reading high
        print ("Waiting for PIR to settle ...")
        time.sleep(2)
 
    print ("  Ready")
    
    current_time = int(time.time())

    while True:
        
        motion_sensor_reading = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)
        
        if current_mode == 0:
            player.play()
            next_mode = 1
        
        if current_mode == 1:
            motion_detect_bool = check_motion_sensor(Current_Motion, Previous_Motion)
            if motion_detect_bool == True:
                print("still motioned!")
                next_mode = 1
            elif motion_detect_bool == False:
                if player.position() > eyeopen-2: #loops the eyeopen mode before eyeclosed happens
                    eyeopen()                
        
        if current_mode == 1:
            motion_detect_bool = check_motion_sensor(Current_Motion, Previous_Motion)
            if motion_detect_bool == True:
                print("still motioned!")
                if int(player.position()) > eyeopen+5:
                    eyeopen_mode()
            elif motion_detect_bool == False:
                print("no more motion!")
                next_mode = 0

        if next_mode is not None:
            current_mode = next_mode #changes mode
        
        time.sleep(5) #sleep for 5 seconds
        print("current mode is " + str(current_mode))
        print("motion detect reading is " + str(motion_sonsor_reading))
        print("current time is " + str(current_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("  Quit")
    # Reset GPIO settings
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Note: This question isn't Raspberry Pi specific. Please post these kinds of questions in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

This should work:

***Remember to replace the ENDOV variable with the time that the video ends***

```
from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer 
from pathlib import Path
import time #for determining the time of playback
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #for taking signal from GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO_PIR = 7 #The GPIO is plugged into BCM pin 07 (GPIO pin 26)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIR,GPIO.IN) # Set pin as input
 
Current_Motion  = 0 #the current state of motion detection
Previous_Motion = 0 #the previous state

VIDEO_PATH = Path("/media/pi/ASTEYES/sensor_py_birds.mp4")

player = OMXPlayer(VIDEO_PATH)


''' The following variables need to be changed from one
    program to the next. They are the times when each event happens
    in the videos.'''
eyeclosed = 2 #eyeclosed
eyeopen = 102 #eyeopen
ENDOV = 116 #IMPORTANT: Replace this with the actual end of the video

current_mode = 0 #determines which mode the player is in

motion_detect_bool = False #boolean for detecting motion

def eyeclosed_mode():
    player.set_position(eyeclosed)
    print("player seeked to " + str(player.position()) + "for eyeclosed")

def eyeopen_mode():
    player.set_position(eyeopen)
    print("player seeked to " + str(player.position()) + "for eyeopen")


def check_motion_sensor(current_motion, previous_motion):
    current_motion = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR) # Read PIR state
    time.sleep(1)
    if current_motion == 1 and previous_motion == 0:
        previous_motion = 1
        return True
    elif current_motion == 0 and previous_motion == 1:
        previous_motion = 0
        return False
    print("The motion sensor reading is: " + str(current_motion))

try:
    player.play()
    
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR) == 1: #loop while the motion sensor is setting up and still reading high
        print ("Waiting for PIR to settle ...")
        time.sleep(2)
 
    print ("  Ready")
    
    current_time = int(time.time())

    while True:
        
        motion_detect_bool = check_motion_sensor(Current_Motion, Previous_Motion)

        if motion_detect_bool:
            eyeopen_mode()
        
        if not motion_detect_bool:
            eyeclosed_mode()
                
        if player.position() > eyeopen-7: #loops the eyeclosed mode before eyeopen happens
            eyeclosed_mode()                

        if player.position() > ENDOV-7: #loops the eyeopen mode before video ends
            eyeopen_mode()         

        time.sleep(5) #sleep for 5 seconds
        print("current time is " + str(current_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("  Quit")
    # Reset GPIO settings
    GPIO.cleanup()
```